# Trouble opening a SQL 2005 .dtproj file in VS 2012 or VS 2010 data tools

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I tried to open this old SQL Server 2005 code example from a book, but the conversion wizard for both VS 2010 or VS 2012 won't conver this .dtproj, it fails every time and there is really no good reason in the conversion log to help.  I assume the project type has changed dramatically or maybe not, I don't know but I can't figure out how to convert it so I can open it again in newer versions of VS (after VS 2008).

Answer (score 0):

You might try using an older version like SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.  I think that is the proper version for 2005 code.  I'm sure there was a free version.